# How can I read the first line from every text file in a specific directory and add each line to a listbox in a C# WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a directory that Contains x amount of text files. The first Line on each text file needs to be added to a list box in a WPF application when the application starts.  How can I read the first line from every text file and add each line to my list box?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Basically how would I read the first line from each file in the directory and add it to the listbox?

Comment: You should update your question with more detail about what you are trying to do. In addition, you should post any information around what you have already tried, and any code that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
    foreach (var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\folder"))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            listBox.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for!  The only thing I changed was removing "+ Environment.NewLine" as that caused an extra blank line under each listbox item.  Thanks!